# sending a mail with Drupal's user_save

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I have a website that has to insert users in a Drupal database. I include the Drupal bootstrap file and call the `user_save()` function.

The paramenters I pass to `user_save` are: the first one a stdClass with property 'status'=1, and the second parameter is (what's expected to be sent, because the insert works just fine).

The problem I'm having is that the user receives no confirmation email. I think `user_save` should send the user an email, but it doesn't. Maybe I'm missing something here, so your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The second paramater should be an array:

```
 user_save($account, array('status' => 1));
```

You can always look at http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_save/6 to understand the user_save function in detail..

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, you have checked the settings for sending email on registration?
admin/config/people/accounts

Sometimes there are problem with email on crappy servers/some hosts are limiting the php mail function. Here is a simple php mail call you could try if you're not sure if the mail-function runs without problem on your server.

```
<?php
    $to = 'youremail@yourhost.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: youremail@yourhost.com' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: youremail@yourhost.com' . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```